# SslStream - AuthenticateAsClient Forced even with TcpClient NetworkStream with a port of 143 (http)

Tags: c#, imap, sslstream

Im having a hard time trying to connect to:
imap.suddenlink.net:143
(IMAP 4)

Strangely, I can never seem to receive data back after sending a command by writing to the NetworkStream.
Command seems to write fine, but when reading, I don't get anything apart from uint of 10 which I believe is a space or \n

If I attempt to wrap NetworkStream with SslStream to read from that to see if it handles anything better, I get struck with a must be authenticated exception.
So if I were to authenticate, it would end up with an exception of: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.

What am I doing wrong?

```
_tcpClientNetworkStream = new TcpClient(dnsOfHostname, port).GetStream();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(tag + " LOGIN \"user\" \"pass\"\r\n");
_tcpClientNetworkStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
//I then try retrieve the response from the network stream using .ReadByte()    
//First readbyte will return 10 as int, which then cast to a byte and that to a string results in a space
```

Comment: What is your actual send code?

Comment: And do you terminate your command with "\r\n" ?

Comment: @Max Updated code with the Command Write I do. And yes I use \r\n termination

Comment: Still need help on this, Its pretty odd :|

Comment: Well, the first thing your code needs to do is read the greeting response from the IMAP server immediately after connecting before you send a LOGIN command.

Comment: @jstedfast Theres a greeting to be read right after creating that NetworkStream? What am I looking for? A "OK"?

Comment: Have you read the IMAP specification?

Comment: @jstedfast Yeah but at this stage I dont know wether to read 4.1 or just plain 4 RFC :/

Comment: Read the specification for [IMAP4rev1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501) - it contains everything you need for the basic protocol. After that, you can have fun reading the specifications for the 60+ extensions.

Comment: @jstedfast I thought that alright. So with the on-connect greeting, I am expecting a "OK". But what circumstances would I get a preauth and why would I ever end up with a BYE response? mail.btinternet.com actually gives me this basically always.

Comment: You likely will never see `* PREAUTH`. A server will send `* BYE` if your IP has been blocked or if the server is going down for maintenance or if it is already serving too many connections or anything along those lines.

Comment: FWIW, I have written a fully open source IMAP library at https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit which you may find useful at least for seeing how a lot of this is done. It also implements a whole slew of the extensions (all of the most commonly found extensions and some that I just thought were cool). If you have questions, my email address is listed on my github page and I do try to make a point of responding to queries about MailKit.